# CUDA reduction - race condition?

Tags: c++, cuda

Please consider the following code and accompanying explanatory image that I have obtained from a tutorial.  Its purpose is to demonstrate a parallel reduction in CUDA.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

__global__ void sumSingleBlock(int* d)
{
  int tid = threadIdx.x;

  // Number of participating threads (tc) halves on each iteration
  for (int tc = blockDim.x, stepSize = 1; tc > 0; tc >>= 1, stepSize <<= 1)
  {
    // Thread must be allowed to write
    if (tid < tc)
    {
      // We need to do A + B, where B is the element following A, so first we 
      // need to find the position of element A and of element B      
      int posA = tid * stepSize * 2;
      int posB = posA + stepSize;

      // Update the value at posA by adding the value at posB to it
      d[posA] += d[posB];
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  cudaError_t status;

  const int count = 8;
  const int size = count * sizeof(int);
  int* h = new int[count];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    h[i] = i+1;

  int* d;
  status = cudaMalloc(&d, size);

  status = cudaMemcpy(d,h,size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  sumSingleBlock<<<1,count/2>>>(d);

  int result;
  status = cudaMemcpy(&result,d,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cout << "Sum is " << result << endl;

  getchar();

  cudaFree(d);
  delete [] h;

  return 0;
}
```

[image: Process of reduction]

Now, I can understand the general principle of reduction as outlined in the diagram.  What I don't get is how there is no race condition in the additions **(*)**:

So clearly all four threads will run the loop the same number of times; only if `tid < tc` will they do something useful.  Thread #0 adds 1 and 2 and stores the result in element 0.  Its second iteration then accesses element 2.  Meanwhile, thread #1's first iteration is adding 3 and 4 and storing the result in element 2.

**What if thread #0 starts iteration 2 before thread #1 has finished iteration 1?  That would mean thread #0 could read 3 instead of 7, or possibly a torn value(?)** There isn't any synchronisation here, so is the code just wrong?

**(*)** Note: I don't know for sure that there are no race conditions, I am trusting purely in the tutorial being correct with safe code.

Comment: Yes, the code is just wrong. Synchronization is needed in the general case.  Even if you want to posit warp-synchronous behavior, the provided code has issues.  You probably should use a better tutorial.  NVIDIA has a [reduction sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) and there is a [tutorial by Mark Harris](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) for it.  This version of the tutorial is missing a treatment of `volatile` for warp-synchronous sections, however.

Comment: [`thrust::reduce`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga69434d74f2e6117040fb38d1a28016c2)

Comment: Thanks Robert Crovella; maybe you could post this as answer?

Comment: Curious as to who downvoted this also...

Comment: I should say that I have done digging and read through all the comments posted on the tutorial and someone else spotted this; the author responded saying that the `__syncthreads();` call should be added after the `if` statement in the kernel.

Comment: You probably have enough information to answer this yourself, if you wish to.  It's perfectly legal on SO to answer your own questions.  I would say a high quality posting would provide an actual link to its source material.  You might want to edit the question to do that, or provide it in the answer, along with your findings.

Comment: I'm sorry that you think getting reputation for answering the question I originally asked, i.e. "is this code wrong", is a waste of your time.  I'll post an answer with what I found.  Thanks for the input again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is wrong, and it needs a `__syncthreads()` call as shown below.

```
__global__ void sumSingleBlock(int* d)
{
  int tid = threadIdx.x;

  // Number of participating threads (tc) halves on each iteration
  for (int tc = blockDim.x, stepSize = 1; tc > 0; tc >>= 1, stepSize <<= 1)
  {
    // Thread must be allowed to write
    if (tid < tc)
    {
      // We need to do A + B, where B is the element following A, so first we 
      // need to find the position of element A and of element B      
      int posA = tid * stepSize * 2;
      int posB = posA + stepSize;

      // Update the value at posA by adding the value at posB to it
      d[posA] += d[posB];
    }
     __syncthreads();
  }
}
```